# Android: how to programmatically get layout's width

Tags: android, layout

Well, the title is not really exhaustive but it's how I would fix the problem.
If there are other solutions, they are welcome.

I'm testing my app in 2 emulators and this is the output:

[image: 1024x600 mdpi:]

[image: 480x800 hdpi:]

It's a row of an ExpandableListView and contains a title on the left and a preview on the right.
The preview is supposed to be cut if too long.
The problem is that in the first case it's too short and in the second one too long.

This is the layout of the row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/elv_title_1_selector"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/evl_grp_indicator"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="indDown"
        android:src="@drawable/indicator_selector" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cbWarning"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/warning_selector"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/LogoButtonText"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGroupName"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@drawable/elv_title_1_selector"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPreview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've set the text size of the preview to 12sp and I programmatically cut the text if longer than *n* chars.
What I need is to cut it larger on the first case and shorter on the second.

Any ideas how to ?

Comment: you can set singleLine = "true" and ellipsize = "end" for textview in your xml so this will put ... at end of text in textview if going out of screen

Comment: You can design for different screen sizes. For instance for xhdpi you have set text 12sp and you add the new layout with same name under xxhdpi where the text size will be 15sp.

Comment: add property android:singleLine = "true" in txtPreview and set its width to wrap_content.

Comment: @JawadZeb: I thought only pictures could be designed for different screens, not layouts.

Comment: @marco: ia have read some post related to screen sizes i found a method which adjusts the text accoring to the screen size.Here is the function.


public float convertFromDp(int input) {
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return ((input - 0.5f) / scale);
}

//Usage
myTextView.setTextSize(convertFromDp(15));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue add an attribute `android:singleLine="true"`and `android:ellipsize="end"` for the `textview`.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPreview"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@drawable/elv_title_1_selector"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I was cutting the text and adding a _..._ a the end by my self but this is done automatically adding your code. Perfect.

Comment: Now the problem is that the preview could be multiline but I will fix it.

Comment: Do not fix your TextView width, it may cause problems for some devices. so replace android:layout_width="110dp" with android:layout_width="wrap_content" or android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: @Karheek: All the rows in the ExandableListView must have the same title size. With _wrap_content_ it becomes horrible.

Comment: Ya. You are right it depends on your requirement. Anyway you have added android:singleLine="true" so it will in a single line.

Comment: You should fix your answer, btw. The TextView to be changed is _" android:id="@+id/txtPreview"_ not what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

First of all add `android:singleLine="true"`  and `android:ellipsize="end"` in your second `TextView`

```
<TextView 
...
 android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
...
/>
```

for Managing the text size on different device

create folder

```
values
values-v21
values-sw600
```

and add `dimes.xml` and specify your `textsize` for different resolutions

Comment: Your answer adds even more useful details, thanks. I already accepted the other answer as it came first.

Comment: Welcome @marco no issue. for your info you can change your decision at any time about answer acceptance